# How to implement jQuery?

Tags: javascript

I want to add a slideshow in my Drupal website. But i dont know how to add jQuery file in Drupal.

Answer (score 3):

Drupal already ships with jQuery, you don't need to add it yourself.

- Drupal 6 comes with v1.2 (can be upgraded to 1.3.2 with [jQuery Update](http://drupal.org/project/jquery_update))
- Drupal 7 comes with v1.4 (can be upgraded to 1.5.2 with [jQuery Update](http://drupal.org/project/jquery_update), higher with the dev version).

Answer (score 2):

You probably dont want to randomly add a plugin and manipulate the markup on page but rather use the CMS and various modules to achieve your goal. The thing with Drupal is someone has usually done it. In this case the 'views_slideshow' module is probably the best out there.

http://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow

There alot invloved in configuring this initially but when you have done your see the benefits. If you dont use the CMS to your advantage, your going to find it difficult to manage or for most of us, your client would be able to manage it.

Alternatively, you could add a JS file on the theme layer either in your .info file

```
  scripts[] = js/scripts.js
```

Or through a template function

```
function THEME_preprocess_html(&$vars) {

  drupal_add_js(path_to_theme() . '/js/SOMEFILE.js');

}
```

Answer (score 1):

in some cases that you want a specific slideshow that drupal doesnt already have, you need to theme it yourself, you can add your .js file in your drupal .info like this:

```
scripts[] = "scripts/script.js"
```

in other cases other answers are good to go

Answer (score 1):

Here is some more information

**Adding JavaScript**
There are two ways for Themes to easily add JavaScript to a page.

**In .info File**

```
scripts[] = foo.js
```

**In template.php**

```
<?php
function example_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  $options = array(
    'group' => JS_THEME,
  );
  drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'example'). '/foo.js', $options);
}
?>
```

**To add a library**

```
<?php
drupal_add_library('system', 'ui.autocomplete');
?>
```

**JavaScript behaviors**

JavaScript behaviors

Drupal uses a "behaviors" system to provide a single mechanism for attaching JavaScript functionality to elements on a page. The benefit of having a single place for the behaviors is that they can be applied consistently when the page is first loaded and then when new content is added during AHAH/AJAX requests. In Drupal 7 behaviors have two functions, one called when content is added to the page and the other called when it is removed.

Behaviors are registered by setting them as properties of `Drupal.behaviors`. Drupal will call each and pass in a DOM element as the first parameter (in Drupal 7 a settings object will be passed as the second parameter). For the sake of efficiency the behavior function should do two things:

- Limit the scope of searches to the context element and its children. This is done by passing context parameter along to jQuery:
  `jQuery('.foo', context);`
- Avoid processing the same element multiple times.
  In Drupal 6 assign a marker class to the element and use that class to restrict selectors:
  `jQuery('.foo:not(.foo-processed)', context).addClass('foo-processed').css('color', 'red');`
  In Drupal 7 use the jQuery Once plugin that's bundled with core:
  `jQuery('.foo', context).once('foo').css('color', 'red');`